# SDL, opengl es and IOS Handling exceptions

Tags: opengl-es, sdl

I have a problem. When I try to run my project, it crashes without any exceptions. I tried to use “try -  catch” but it caused the same result. Maybe someone can advise me some SDL or opengl es methods to handle this error?

PS:
     glDrawArrays() - Function which leads to an error.

```
 I`m using sdl-1.3, opengl es 1.1, C++, X-Code
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the passed arrays and their sizes are valid on calling glDrawArrays. If not then depending on your graphics card driver weird things can happen, beginning from flying polyons, psychodelic polygon colors, system hangs, or even application exit.

Comment: I`m shure that the problem is in opengl es initialisation or i`m using methods in a wrong way. But i`m interested how to handle the error message

Comment: If on calling glDrawArrays the application exits then I fear there is no way to get any error message. If it does not exit then you could try to use the glGetError function right after the glDrawArrays to get some hints about what is wrong in your GL pipeline.